# Unable to start Oryx with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2, snappy, oryx

I am trying to run Oryx with Hadoop 2.4. Hadoop starts successfully with warning:

*WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable.*

Oryx also starts successfully. But when I ingest data into it, following exception is thrown :

*2014-08-22 14:35:05,835 ERROR [IPC Server handler 3 on 37788] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1408697508855_0002_m_000000_0 - exited : org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
2014-08-22 14:35:05,835 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 37788] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1408697508855_0002_m_000000_0: Error: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
2014-08-22 14:35:05,837 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1408697508855_0002_m_000000_0: Error: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
2014-08-22 14:35:05,840 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1408697508855_0002_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from RUNNING to FAIL_CONTAINER_CLEANUP*

Has anyone faced such kind of issue earlier? Any kind of help will be appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying a few items from your [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/oryx-user/2qZ13T-EAbQ) on the mailing list:

- This may be a problem with the installation's Snappy libraries, but that seems to have been resolved
- The YARN containers are being killed for running past virtual memory limits. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/cloudera/oryx/wiki/FAQ-and-Troubleshooting#container--is-running-beyond-virtual-memory-limits) -- this may be a Java issue you can work around by changing YARN config.
- Final problem seems to be another issue with YARN config, although it's not clear. I suggest starting from fresh config and/or a [distribution](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/cdh/cdh-5-1-0.html) that is preconfigured and known to work, if possible.